# multi line dotted or dashed text-underline

Tags: css

Because CSS text underline only allows a solid line and its position is right at the bottom of strings, I'm using border-bottom plus a little padding to achieve dotted or dashed text underline.

```
h2{border-bottom:1px dotted #999; padding-bottom:5px;}
```

now, the problem is, when the heading (or paragraph, or whatever element) text takes 2 lines or more, the dotted underline simply does what every border does, which is stay on the bottom of the block element. If I use text-underline style, the underline stays with the text, but text-underline only supports a solid line, and as far as I know, no padding.

So how do I display multi line texts with dotted or dashed underline ?

Thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
h2 {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #999;
  display: inline;
}
```

So you receive what you need.
But you have to keep in mind that `<h2>` is then (of course) no longer a block element. But you can "avoid" that by putting a `<h2>` in a `<div>`.

Comment: Thanks. Yep, this is what I need. Actually I'm using <p> for this, and it doesn't matter whether it's considered a block element or not, since it's in a <div> too.

Comment: UPDATE : on the second thought, it needs to be a block element. If it's an inline element, the texts can't cover the whole container width and I can't use text-align justify to align it. Sorry if I'm not being clear

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by your last comment... Could you explain it a bit more detailed? :)

Comment: @Henson, if you wrap it in a `div` an set the `text-align` on that (example http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/mgDqx/)?

Comment: @Gaby : spot on. the text-align must be in the container.
@everyone : thanks

Answer (score 13):

A "bit" late, but there's [a way with text-decoration-style and text-decoration-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-style) to customize the underline in some browsers.

```css
.underline-dashed {
  decoration-line: underline;
  decoration-style: dashed;
}
```

Example:

```css
.underline-dashed {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dashed;
}
```

```html
This is some <span class="underline-dashed">dashed underlined</span> text.
```

Comment: Several years after this answer was posed the support is still very low (pretty much only ff) http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-decoration

Comment: Works in FF, Chrome, Edge

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing similar issue but with <a> tags. In my case it was css float property that was causing the border to appear only under the last line. So I enclosed the <a> tags with <span> tags and moved the css float:left to <span>. It fixed the issue now bottom border appears under all the lines whenever a long link is wrapped to fit the containing div.

The revised css style and HTML structure is as follows:

```css
  a { border-bottom:1px dotted red; }
  span.nav-link { float:left; }
```

```html
<span class="nav-link"><a href="some-page">Test link</a></span>
```

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

```
text-decoration: underline dotted;
text-decoration: underline dashed;
```

Comment: This answer can be improved with explanation, references to documentation, and info about browser support.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration