# Why do some borders not print from an Electron app?

Tags: html, css, printing, electron

In an Electron app, I'm loading an HTML page preloaded with CSS into an `iframe`, then dynamically populating it with content in JavaScript. (All of this is being done from the render process—no IPC is occurring.) After the `iframe` is populated, I'm attempting to print its contents using `iframe.contentWindow.print()`.

As shown below, the script dynamically generates `.item`s, each of which may contain any number of `.row`s. Each `.row` contains two pieces of text at opposite sides of the screen, separated by a `.separator` with a dotted border.

When I load and print this HTML in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari, the PDF generated by `print()` contains every dotted border and looks exactly as the rendered HTML does within the web page (FWIW, the `iframe` is ordinarily "hidden" using `height: 1px; width: 1px; visibility: hidden;`, but this seems to make no difference).

However, within the Electron app, only some of the `.separator` borders render in the print PDF—the others are completely blank and have no border whatsoever. The skipped `.separator`s are the same every time the document is printed.

The PDF should look like this (generated from Chrome):

[image: Correct PDF]

But the Electron version looks like this:

[image: Incorrect PDF]

I've tried using other techniques to generate the dotted lines (such as a custom `border-image` or using a gradient `background` similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22379502/css-gradient-to-produce-dotted-line)), neither of which have worked. I've tried including the `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact` and `color-adjust: exact` CSS rules, which similarly make no difference. Setting the `style` tag to `media="print"` only introduces more issues and does nothing to fix the borders.

How can I force the generated PDF from the `iframe.contentWindow`'s `print()` function to contain every dotted border in the `iframe`?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  .item {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}

.item {
  padding: 0.25in;
  line-height: 0.35in;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.label {
  text-align: center
}

.text1 {
  text-align: left;
}

.text2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.separator {
  margin-left: 1pt;
  margin-right: 1pt;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* These last two rules are likely superfluous */
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  color-adjust: exact !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="text1">Text 1</p>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <p class="text2">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <p class="label">Label for Item</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="row">
    <p class="text1">Text 1</p>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <p class="text2">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="text1">Text 1</p>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <p class="text2">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <p class="label">Label for Item</p>
</div>
```

I'm using the following software:

- Electron v1.8.8
- Chrome 69.0.3497.81
- Safari 11.1.2
- Firefox 62.0
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6