# How to change color of text-overflow: ellipsis by hovering it

Tags: html, css

Can someone suggest to change "dotted text color on mouse over" in HTML. I am trying with below code but it didn't work. please help me.

This is my css-------------

```
.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 150px;
/*  color:#ffffff;*/
}

.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList a {
    color: #003c72;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList a:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#003C72;
    width:150px;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

This is my HTML code-------------

```
<div class="gvb-theme-carosuleTooltipMargin">
<div class="gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList">
<a href="#">
<img src="img/cp_star.png" class="gvb-theme-cpSetStarIcon" > <span>CONTO LA LIBRETTA LIBRETTA</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your colour is white after hovering. Which colour should it have?

Comment: What is "dotted text color"?

Comment: What do you want exactly

Comment: dotted text-color?? or dotted border underneath text upon hover?

Comment: @user3876771 you should try googling your question before just asking it. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252597/how-to-add-a-dotted-underline-beneath-html-text as such, this question should be closed.

Comment: No, he wants to use text-overflow: ellipsis. Its a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `class` so as to add dotted below the text on hover :

```
.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList span:hover {
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Change the color part as your needs.etc: `1px dotted #101010;`
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/308wakq6/

Comment: But then he/she has to hover over the text to make it underlined.

Comment: Can someone suggest to change "dotted text color on mouse over"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the two following:

```
.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList:hover {
color:#ffffff;
}

.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList:hover > span{
color:#ffffff;
}
```

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/olivier_royo/s159y4m1/

Answer (score -2):

you need to do this:

```
.gvb-theme-cpCaroToolTipList a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#003C72;
    width:150px;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please mark which lines are the ones you've added compared to the original code with some explanation on why that works? Thanks!