# Combine shiny::markdown with tippy::tippy_this

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to dynamically render markdown and create tooltips on the output?

I imagine some .md document like

```
# myfile.md
This is a <span class="tippy", data-tippy-content="markdown is a simple text 
format">markdown</span> document.
```

(the idea of "data-tippy-content" comes from the [examples section](https://tippy.john-coene.com/articles/examples.html#defaults) of the "tippy" package.)

The shiny app would then look like

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
        shiny::markdown(readLines("myfile.md")),
        tippy_this(".tippy")
 ),
 server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

However, when I run this, I get an error "must pass tooltip.".

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: I just learned that there is this [new HTML tag `attr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38309183/216064) that seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using the CRAN version (`0.1.0` from 2018) whereas the docs and the examples refer to the dev version (`1.0.0`), i.e. your code works fine using the dev version.

Note: I also fixed a typo in your md, HTML attributes should not be separated by a `,`.

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    shiny::markdown(readLines("myfile.md")),
    tippy_this(".tippy")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {}
)
```

[image]

**myfile.md**

```
This is a <span class="tippy" data-tippy-content="markdown is a simple text 
format">markdown</span> document.
```